# Can't display calculated value

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Goal:
Display the value of the calculation in the html page.

problem:

> After you have clicked on the submit
>   button, the calculation will be
>   beginning. Thereafter, the page
>   started reloading again by executing
>   "window.onload". This consq makes that
>   I can't view the calculated result.

I just wanna "window.onload" to be loaded once and after that I wanna add more data in the page by pressing submit button without reloading the whole page again. After you have pressed the submit button, that data should be visible.

// fullmetalboy

---

```
    <script type ="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="scripts/data.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id ="container">
        <div id ="header">

        </div>
        <div id ="content">

            <table id ="pricetable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Articlenumber</th>
                        <th>Product</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Price</th>
                        <th>Quantity</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody> 
                    <tr>
                        <td>223</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                        <td><input type ="text" size ="3" value ="1"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>223</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                        <td><input type ="text" size ="3" value ="1"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>223</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                        <td><input type ="text" size ="3" value ="1"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>223</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>a</td>
                        <td>250</td>
                        <td><input type ="text" size ="3" value ="1"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>





        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

---

```
window.onload = init; 




function init() 
{
    createForm();
    addColumn();
    addRow();
}



function addColumn()
{

    var tabellHead = document.getElementById("pricetable").tHead;

    for (var a=0; a<tabellHead.rows.length; a++) 
    {
        var nyTH = document.createElement('th');
        tabellHead.rows[a].appendChild(nyTH);
        nyTH.innerHTML = "Summa";
    }


    var tabellBody = document.getElementById("pricetable");

    for (var b=1; b<tabellBody.rows.length; b++) 
    {
        var nyTD = document.createElement('td');
        tabellBody.rows[b].appendChild(nyTD);
        nyTD.innerHTML = "";
    }

}



function addRow()
{
    var newRow  = document.createElement('tr');
    newRow.setAttribute('id', "sumrow");



    var ca1 = document.createElement('td');
    var ca2 = document.createElement('td');
    var ca3 = document.createElement('td');
    var ca4 = document.createElement('td');
    var ca5 = document.createElement('td');
    var ca6 = document.createElement('td');

    var text = document.createTextNode("asdf");


    var font = document.createElement('font');
    font.setAttribute('color', 'white');
    font.appendChild(text);



    ca6.appendChild(font);

    newRow.appendChild(ca1);
    newRow.appendChild(ca2);
    newRow.appendChild(ca3);
    newRow.appendChild(ca4);        
    newRow.appendChild(ca5);    
    newRow.appendChild(ca6);     

    var t  = document.getElementById('pricetable');

    t.appendChild(newRow);  
}



function createForm()
{
    var t  = document.getElementById('content');

    var a = "<form><input onclick='tttest();' value='Rensa' type='submit'></form>";

    t.innerHTML += a;
}




function calc()
{



        var lass = document.getElementById("pricetable");

        var tabellBody = asss.getElementsByTagName("tr");


        for (var b=1; b<tabellBody.length; b++) 
        {
            var godis = tabellBody[b].cells[4].childNodes[0];
            var godia = tabellBody[b].cells[3];

            var a = godia.innerHTML * godis.value;

            var text = document.createTextNode(a);


            //tabellBody.rows[b].cells[5].innerHTML = a;

            var celler = tabellBody[b].getElementsByTagName("td");

            var medelelement = celler[celler.length - 1];

            medelelement.appendChild(text);

        }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the submit button to a normal button so that it doesn't submit the form when clicked.

```
var a = "<form><input onclick='tttest();' value='Rensa' type='button' /></form>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just return false in the onclick handler from the submit button, that should prevent the form from submitting

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function() {
    /*do my calc stuff*/
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Submit button should return false, like this

```
onsubmit = "calc(); return false;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are submitting a form, hence your page will obviously reload.

You have to either

a) Prevent the form submit and calculate the result.

b) Use AJAX to submit the form without having to reload the page.